# where clause in ajax call daterangepicker

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, daterangepicker

THE HTML code

```
  <div class="col-md-4 input-group input-group-lg search">
     <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa fa-calendar red"></i></span>
     <input id="config" class="form-control placeholded" placeholder="Select the date to filter records" type="text" data-cid="<? echo $cid; ?>">
   </div>
```

THE SCRIPT code how to put the current client id here?

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.search i').click(function() {
      $(this).parent().find('input').click();
    });
    updateConfig();

    function updateConfig() {
      var options = {};
      // remove other code for space
      $('#config').daterangepicker(options, function(start, end, label) { 
      var startDate = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'); var endDate = end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      var cid = $(this).data("cid");
      passDate(startDate,endDate,cid); 
       });

    }

  });

function passDate(startDate,endDate,cid) {
$('.loader').show();
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
        url: 'invoiceresult.php', // the url where we want to POST
        data: 'startDate='+startDate+'&endDate='+endDate+'cid='+cid, // our data object
    })
    // remove for space
}
}
```

THE PHP this is the WHERE clause

```
 if((!empty($_POST['startDate'])&&(!empty($_POST['endDate'])))) {   // Check whether the date is empty          
    $startDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['startDate']));
    $endDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['endDate']));
    $cid = $_POST['cid'];
    $sresult = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE (invoiceCreated BETWEEN  "'.$startDate.'" and "'.$endDate.'") AND cid=:cidg');  // Execute the query
    $sresult->execute(array(":cidg)=>$cid);
    $num_rows = $sresult->fetchColumn(); //Check whether the result is 0 or greater than 0.
    // remove other code for space
```

SCREENSHOT
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjCEM.jpg)

with this code the result is "undefined" Hope someone will help. Thanks

Comment: you are currently searching based on time, where is you id on the main page?,what event is triggered to get the info based on the id?

Comment: _“I just want to get the current client_id”_ – where _from_?

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys... it's on the screenshot. BTW. I just need to get the specific company/client ID before or within the ajax call

Comment: currently with that code I get all the invoices including all the clients/company. in the link viewinvoices.php?cid=80160001 it has already an id but when ajax calls to invoiceresult.php the id left behind after the call.

Answer (score 0):

Add an data-attribut to one element, e.g. the input#config, with your client_id. Then you can read it in javascript and use it value.

**HTML**

`<input id="config" class="form-control placeholded" placeholder="Select the date to filter records" type="text" data-client-id="client_id" />`

**JS**

`$('#config').daterangepicker(options, function(start, end, label) {
      var startDate = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'); var endDate = end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      passDate(startDate,endDate, document.getELementById("config").getAttribute("data-client-id"));
});`

Comment: got it but do I need to pass that ID inside the ajax call data:? 
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
        url: 'invoiceresult.php', // the url where we want to POST
        data: 'startDate='+startDate+'&endDate='+endDate, // our data object
    })

Comment: Yes. One way could be data: 'startDate='+startDate+'&endDate='+endDate+'clientId='+client-id. Another way would be to use a variable like "var data = {startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate, clientId: client-id};" instead of an url.

Comment: I inserted these code "passDate(startDate,endDate, document.getELementById("config").getAttribute("data-client-id"));" and "data: 'startDate='+startDate+'&endDate='+endDate+'cid='+cid," still not working mate... anyway here's the query: $sresult = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE (invoiceCreated BETWEEN  "'.$startDate.'" and "'.$endDate.'") AND cid=:cidg');  // Execute the query
$sresult->execute(array(":cidg"=>$cid));

Comment: Did you edited your function too? "function passDate(startDate,endDate, cid) {"
Also, "getELementById" is wrong, "getElementById" is right. What is your error message?

Could you update your start-post with your new code please?

Comment: hi mate, just updated the new code but still get no results. with the updated code the datepicker will show but the "$('.loader').show();" won't show up and it's hangup there... :(

Comment: i think the problem there is with this code "passDate(startDate,endDate, document.getELementById("config").getAttribute("data-client-id"));" because that functions is for daterangepicker and nothing to do about it?